# NoMethodError (private method `gsub!' called for Thu Oct 10 11:56:28 UTC 2013:Time):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I'm currently using Ruby 1.8.7 (required by hosting provider...moving off soon).

With that aside, I'm getting the following error,

```
NoMethodError (private method `gsub!' called for Thu Oct 10 11:56:28 UTC 2013:Time):
  app/models/time_tracked.rb:140:in `search'
  app/models/time_tracked.rb:140:in `sort!'
  app/models/time_tracked.rb:140:in `search'
```

The line in question (140) is:

```
sub.sort! { |x, y| Time.zone.parse(x[1]) <=> Time.zone.parse(y[1]) } if sub.length > 1
```

As I understand it, the error is thrown because I'm trying to parse a time object instead of a string, but I'm unclear on how to correct this.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Update: Cortex's answer resolved the initial question, but implementing it now causes the following on my view,

```
ActionView::Template::Error (private method `sub!' called for Thu Oct 10 11:56:28 UTC 2013:Time):
    23:<td><strong><%= (v.index(item) == 0) ? k : '' %></strong></td>
    24:<td><%= item[0] %></td>
    25:<td>
    26:<%= DateTime.strptime(item[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M ').in_time_zon e(Time.zone).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")%>
    27:</td>
    28:<td>
    29:<%= DateTime.strptime(item[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').in_time_z
one(Time.zone).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")%>
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: What value does `sub` have? It looks like an array of pairs.

Comment: sub has a starting DateTime and ending DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `x[1]` is a `Time` object. So try:

```
sub.sort! { |x, y| Time.zone.parse(x[1].to_s) <=> Time.zone.parse(y[1].ti_s) } if sub.length > 1
```

I tested this on Ruby 2. Hope it works in Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Thanks, that got me past my initial error, but now I'm seeing the new error in my view as posted in my update above.

Comment: The view code is above.  The error is on lines 26 and 29.  It doesn't like the formatting of the item[1] and item[2].  If I use your code, and simply output item[1] and item[2] then it renders.

Comment: Give me the value of `item[1]`.

Comment: As-is: 2013-01-20 22:43:24, but I need it to be in the format: 01/20/2013 10:43 PM

Comment: Assuming `item[1]` is an String, it worked for me in Ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: I was incorrect about item[1] it actually is: Thu Oct 10 11:56:28 UTC 2013, how do I then get it to 10/10/2013 11:56 AM?  Thanks!